# Case sensitivity not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, collation, string-searching

I have an issue where I keep getting the value 'CtP_PETER_Fact' out of the query below. It should be a case sensitive where-clause. I tried it in a few different ways: setting the COLLATE statement after 'Where ObjectName' in the select, after the regular expression and creating the column with the collation. I keep getting the output I would not expect. Is it some issue with my regular expression maybe? I did a lot of experimenting with the regular expression as well, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nameFacts') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #nameFacts;


CREATE TABLE #nameFacts (


    objectname varchar(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
    ObjectType varchar(40)

)


insert into #nameFacts (objectname, ObjectType)
values
 ('BPD_Inslap_Fact','Fact')
,('CTP_HENK_FACT','Fact')
,('CTP_PETER_Fact','Fact')
,('CTP_PETER_FACT','Fact')
,('CtP_PETER_Fact','Fact')
,('C0P_PETER_Fact','Fact')
,('C0P_PETER_FACT','FACT')


SELECT *
FROM #nameFacts
WHERE
ObjectName --COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
            LIKE '[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z][_][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][_][F][a][c][t]' --COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nameFacts') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #nameFacts;
```

I keep getting the output below, where I would not expect the value 'CtP_PETER_Fact'. I am on SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU 17.

[image: the output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[A-Z]` is a *range* of characters. The characters in the range depend on the *sort order* defined by the collation:

```
SELECT 
    SV.number, 
    CHAR(SV.number) 
FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
WHERE 
    SV.[type] = 'P'
    AND SV.number BETWEEN 1 AND 255
    AND CHAR(SV.number) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS LIKE '[A-Z]'
ORDER BY 
    CHAR(SV.number) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e1c9f65764436371602cb1c719d581f0)

Partial output:

| number | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 65 | A |
| 97 | a |
| 193 | Á |
| 225 | á |
| 224 | à |
| 192 | À |
| 194 | Â |
| 226 | â |
| 196 | Ä |
| 228 | ä |
| ... | ... |

As you can see, many characters you might not expect are defined to sort within that range.

To match just certain uppercase alphas, you would need:

```
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
```

Or use a collation where the sort order for the range A-Z matches your requirements, e.g. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`.

The case-sensitive or case-insensitive part of a collation only affects equality comparisons. `LIKE '[A]'` would match both 'a' and 'A' under a case-insensitive collation, but only 'A' with a case-sensitive collation.